# Electromagnetic Wave Spectroscopy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, spectroscopy

If a material has a non-zero second order susceptibility and you are impinging two electromagnetic waves at frequency f1 and f2 simultaneously on this material, what is the maximum number of frequencies that you can observe from this material? Assume that all higher order (higher than 2) susceptibilities are zero and count also the frequencies f1 and f2, but do not count the constant term.

My initial guess is three different frequencies since the material will emit a response to both f1 and f2 and the interaction between the two.  Not sure what equation would prove this or if I'm completely wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).